# Kill IF process exist in Windows

Tags: windows, if-statement, process, kill

I want to kill a process ONLY IF the process exists, I want to do this because I have a tool that runs only if there is no error and I made some tests and indeed there is an error when I try to kill a process that doesn't exists. This is the line I use to kill a process:

```
taskkill /f /IM notepad.exe
```

But I want to validate it only executes when the process EXISTS.

Thank you!!!

Comment: @echo off tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" | find /i "notepad.exe" >nul && ( taskkill /f /im notepad.exe )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/232703/taskkill-exe-dont-throw-an-error-if-the-process-is-not-running) question, you should try this code:

```
taskkill /f /im notepad.exe /fi "memusage gt 40" 2>NUL | findstr SUCCESS >NUL && if errorlevel 1 ( echo Notepad was not killed ) else ( echo Notepad was killed )
```

If that does not help, you can look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/232703/taskkill-exe-dont-throw-an-error-if-the-process-is-not-running) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854708/taskkill-in-an-if-condition) question.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I tried that too but for some reason it returns: "FIND: Invalid Switch" after I tried: tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "nodepad.exe">NUL if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" taskkill /f /im notepad.exe can you tried to do this in your computer? run it without notepad open and with notepad open the thing is it returns me nothing it notepad is open and it returns success if it is open. I think the problem is with my SO because it is a WIN7 64bits any advice? Thank you

Comment: Ok, try my updated code. If it is successful, it will print 'Notepad was killed', else it will print 'Notepad was not killed'. I have tested this code with my computer, Win7 64 bit, and it seems to work in both an administrator and non-administrator command prompt. Hope it works!

Comment: Really helpful thanks. If you just want the output without an error and without the different messages then the abbreviated version is: taskkill /f /im notepad.exe /fi "memusage gt 40"